# CSS: how to get two floating divs inside another div

Tags: css

I'm sure this a common problem, but couldn't find the exact answer :)

I have two divs inside another div. I want the two divs to be on the same level, one floating to the left and the other to the right. But they won't get inside the parent div unless I use `position: absolute` on the parent. But then the child-divs won't stay on the same level :S

```
#main {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

#left_menu {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

    <div id ="main">
    <div id ="left_menu>&blablabal</div>
    <div id ="content">blablb</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `margin-left` of `#content` should include the width of `#left_menu`. Thus should be

```
#content {
    margin-left: 170px;
    /* float: right; */ /* no need for a float here */
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

You also don't need a `position:absolute` for your `#main` (unless other purposes)

So finally:

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
#main {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#left_menu {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 170px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
.c{clear:both;}
--></style>
    <div id="main">
    <div id="left_menu>&amp;blablabal</div>
    <div id="content">blablb</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c"></div>
```

`.c` is to clear and pushes the bottom content off the floats.

Comment: This just helped me a lot - except to get it to work on my current page layout, I had to add 'display inline block' and 'position fixed' to the 'content' div.

Answer (score 2):

What about this its all to do with your width on your container.

This works for me.

```
    <style type="text/css"><!--
        .Content{
        Width:100%;
        }

        .FloatLeft{
        float:left;
        }
        .FloatRight{
        float:Right;
        }
-->
    </style>

        <div class="Content">
        <div class="FloatLeft"></div>
        <div class="FloatRight"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to 'float' the main div, or use a clearing `<div>` or `<br>` after your content and left menu `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not "staying on the same level", but it's about the size of the container div.

This might help you: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/63079

Answer (score 0):

The nicest and easiest thing to do is to set `overflow: hidden` on the container, `#main`. I don't *think* this works in IE6 though.

Answer (score 0):

try giving the main div an `overflow: hidden;` and taking away it's `position: absolute;`
which will give it a height equivalent to the greater height of the floating divs

Also, I don't know if you copied it from your page, but you're missing a close quotation in your left_menu id=""

Answer (score 0):

```
#main{
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
}
```

and remove absolute to the parent;

```
#left_menu,#content{
 ....
 vertical-align:top;
}
```