# How to top align two divs inside a third one?

Tags: html, css

I need left div as menu and right as content.
I'm trying to adopt the accepted answer from this post:
[CSS: how to get two floating divs inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790648)

```
#container {width:900px;}
#left {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 500px;    
    margin-left: 170px;
}
.clearBoth{clear:both;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left">leftMenu</div>
<div id="right">rightContent</div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

## left and #right should be top aligned but #right is bellow #left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the right div a float too?

```
#right {
width: 500px;    
margin-left: 170px;
float: left;
}
```

a jsfiddle to show you it works :)

http://jsfiddle.net/LtUzc/

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyOne. Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
#container {width:900px;}
#left {
    width: 500px;
    float: left;
}
#right {
    width: 500px;    

float: left;

}
.clearBoth{clear:both;}    

<div id="container">
<div id="left">leftMenu</div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
<div id="right">rightContent</div>

</div>
```