# How to manage CSS layout dependencies?

Tags: css, css-float

This question: [CSS: how to get two floating divs inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790648/css-how-to-get-two-floating-divs-inside-another-div)
shows how to get a variable width box to the right of a fixed width one.

However, we have

```
#left_menu {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin-left: 170px;   /* must be kept as left_menu.width+20 */
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

If we change the width of left_menu, and forget that margin-left was supposed to be this +20, then things go bad.

What's the best practice for tracking these kinds of layout dependencies in CSS?

Comment: Suppose you could use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, then you can use variables and do your calculations there

Answer (score 3):

The (probably) best solution is to use a CSS preprocessor such as SASS. You can do a really simple variable assignment and calculation such as:

```
$leftMenuWidth: 150px;

#left_menu {
    width: $leftMenuWidth;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin-left: $leftMenuWidth + 20;   /* must be kept as left_menu.width+20 */
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

[CSS calc()](http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) is coming along, but it's not quite what you're looking to do.

Another solution, depending on what you're browser compatibility requirements are is [`flexbox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). You can mix fixed width + fluid width elements together and have the browser calculate layout for you. Flexbox can do a lot more as well, but that's for another question. Read the guide I linked on CSS-tricks for a good overview.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `margin` on the `#content` element, you could add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the *content*, and set `margin-right` on the floated element.

```css
#left_menu {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;  /* <-- push the content to the right */
  background-color: orange;
}

#content {
  overflow-x: hidden;  /* <-- prevent from wrapping */
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/ELUcOvo/1/edit)**